# I keep receiving a null value despite assigning the value to it

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to assign API response to global array list in Kotlin, but the arraylist remain null outside the handleResponse function
var disposable: Disposable? = null
    lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    var sensorsData = ArrayList()

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

    showReading("Jxh7GGbk5S5KaBcnlQ4vUw")
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

}
fun showReading(token: String) {

    disposable = client.sensorData(token)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(this::handleResponse)

}
fun handleResponse(sensorData: SensorNode) {

    this.sensorsData.add(sensorData)
    Log.d("SENSOR DATA", "" + sensorsData.get(0)) // Works
}
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    Log.d("SENSOR DATA", "" + sensorsData.get(0)) // Return Null
    val sensor = LatLng(-6.8, 39.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sensor).title("Sensor Node 1"))
}
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    disposable?.dispose()
}
```

Comment: When are you calling handleResponse method? Perhaps onMapReady has been executed first before you have inserted items in your array

Comment: before onMapReady

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `showReading` and `mapFragment.getMapAsync` are two asynchronous calls, so you have no guarantee which one will finish first. The fastest way to handle this - start them simultaneously and wait before both completed and then act.

If you want to use reactive-streams paradigm you can do the following:

```
  Single.create<GoogleMap> { emitter ->
            map.getMapAsync { emitter.onSuccess(it) }
        }.zipWith(sensorData(token), BiFunction<GoogleMap, SensorNode, Unit> { map, node -> 
            //do what you want with map and sensordata
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(this::handleResponse)
```